# Where is the error in my SQL query regarding Invalid Column Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Code:

```
SELECT 
    [ADO NET Destination].Vendor_ID, 
    [ADO NET Destination].Vendor, 
    [ADO NET Destination].Address1, 
    [ADO NET Destination].Address2, 
    [ADO NET Destination].City,
    [ADO NET Destination].Zip
FROM
    [ADO NET Destination]
WHERE 
    ((([ADO NET Destination].Parish) IN ("Caddo", "Bossier", "DeSoto", "Webster")));
```

Errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Webster'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'DeSoto'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Bossier'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Caddo'.

Comment: you are using double quotes in your comparison with `Parish`. Strings use single quotes in SQL:`Parish in ('Caddo','Bossier','Desoto',Webster')`

Answer (score 6):

Strings use single-quotes in T-SQL:

```
'Caddo','Bossier','DeSoto','Webster'
```

Comment: They can also use double. If `set quoted_identifier` is `off`. But that is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

why so many ()  in where and double quote for literal? try

```
SELECT 
    [ADO NET Destination].Vendor_ID
  , [ADO NET Destination].Vendor
  , [ADO NET Destination].Address1
  , [ADO NET Destination].Address2
  , [ADO NET Destination].City
  , [ADO NET Destination].Zip
FROM [ADO NET Destination]
WHERE [ADO NET Destination].Parish In ('Caddo','Bossier','DeSoto','Webster');
```